# Use default modifier keys with AutoHotKey Send

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I'm using Autohotkey to map a key combo to a single key. For example, I want to map `Win` + `Mouse back button` to `Enter` using the script:

```
#XButton1::SendInput "{Enter}"
```

However, I also want to be able to use additional modifier keys such that combos like `Win` + `Ctrl` + `Mouse back button` activates `Ctrl`+`Enter`, without explicitly specifying every single combination of `Ctrl`, `Shift`, `Alt`, and `Win`

Basically, I want the same effect without so much redundancy as below

```
#XButton1::SendInput "{Enter}"
#^XButton1::SendInput "^{Enter}"
#+XButton1::SendInput "+{Enter}"
#!XButton1::SendInput "!{Enter}"
#^+XButton1::SendInput "^+{Enter}"
#^!XButton1::SendInput "^!{Enter}"
#+!XButton1::SendInput "+!{Enter}"
#^+!XButton1::SendInput "^+!{Enter}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
*#XButton1::SendInput "{Blind}{LWin up}{Enter}{LWin down}"
```

Turns out `*#XButton1` will interpret `Win` + `Ctrl` + `Mouse back button` as `Win`+`Ctrl`+`Enter`, which is why it didn't work. This modification simulates a release of the `Win` button before pressing `Enter`